# Writing unit test for component that uses a service

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am currently working on unit test of a VueJS project, and I would like to create a `my-component.spec.js` test (with Jest) for a `my-component.vue` component that uses a `myService` service with the `inject` option. The test itself is not important. It's above all about learning how to properly mock a component that uses a service. After doing a lot of research, I tried to write my test that I think is on the right track, but I can't seem to get it to work completely. Here is the code with 3 `console.log` in the test file :

`mock.js` (file containing a simulated method of the `myService` service) :

```
export default function getAllInfos() {
    return [
        {"id": "myId", "name": "myName"}
    ];
}
```

`my-component.spec.js` :

```
import {mount} from "@vue/test-utils";
import MyComponent from "./my-component.vue";
import getAllInfos from "./mock";

describe("MyComponent", () => {
    it("returns the correct value for getAllInfos() method", () => {
        const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
            "provide": {
                myService() {
                    return {
                        "mock": {
                            "getAllInfos": getAllInfos()
                        }
                    };
                },
            },
            data() {
                return {
                    "infos": []
                };
            }
        });

        console.log("getAllInfos = ", wrapper.vm.$options.provide.myService().mock.getAllInfos);

        const test = wrapper.vm.$options.provide.myService().mock.getAllInfos;
        console.log("test = ", test);

        wrapper.setData({"infos": test});
        console.log("infos = ", wrapper.vm.$options.data().infos);

        expect(wrapper.vm.$options.data().infos).toEqual([
            {"id": "myId", "name": "myName"}
        ]);
    });
});
```

I think I'm on the right track because when I run the `npm run test:unit` command, the first 2 `console.log` return the expected result :

```
getAllInfos = [{id: 'myId', name: 'myName'}]
test = [{id: 'myId', name: 'myName'}]
```

However, the 3rd `console.log` seems strange to me :

```
infos = []
```

This means the `infos` data is not assigned by the `test` constant, the content of which is correct.

Anyone have a solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look at the docs ([setData | Vue Test Utils](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/setdata.html#setdata)), then you can see a small but significant difference to your code:

```
// your code:
/* ... */
it("returns the correct value for getAllInfos() method", () => {
  /* ... */

  wrapper.setData({"infos": test});
  
  /* ... */
});
/* ... */

// code in docs:
/* ... */
test('setData demo', async () => {
  /* ... */

  await wrapper.setData({ foo: 'bar' })

  /* ... */
})
```

Yes, the difference is that in the docs, the test is an `async` function and the `setData` is awaited. I think this is the source of your problem.

You could also try (but this is a bit of a workaround):

```
import { createLocalVue, mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
/* ... */
const localVue = createLocalVue()
/* ... */
wrapper.setData({"infos": test});
await localVue.nextTick()
/* ... */
```

Source for `localVue` [here](http://wrapper.setData(%7B%22infos%22:%20test%7D);)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, I missed that detail... However, I just defined my test as an async function and added the `await` keyword on `wrapper.setData(...)`, but the result is still the same for the 3rd `console.log` :(. Also tested the workaround, and that doesn't work either.